# does "while" here means "despite"? does it indicating a contrast?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

does "while" here means "despite"? does it indicating a contrast?
i mean, did the medium spoke of the future?

> This drives him to the consideration of whether these things may not
>   be explained as the reflection of the mind of some other living human
>   being. These considerations have been exhausted by every inquirer in
>   turn, for Spiritualists do not accept their creed in one bound, but
>   make the journey step by step, with much timid testing of the path.
>   Judge Edmonds's epitome of his course is but that which many others
>   have followed. He gives the following reasons for negativing this
>   question of other human minds:
>   *Facts were communicated which were unknown then, but afterward found to be true; like this, for instance when I was absent last winter in
>   Central America, my friends in town heard of my whereabouts and of the
>   state of my health seven times; and on my return, by comparing their
>   information with the entries in my journal it was found to be
>   invariably correct. So, in my recent visit to the West my whereabouts
>   and my condition were told to a medium in this city, **while** I was
>   travelling on the railroad between Cleveland and Toledo. So thoughts
>   have been uttered on subjects not then in my mind, and utterly at
>   variance with my own notions. This has often happened to me and to
>   others, so as fully to establish the fact that it was not our minds
>   that gave birth to or affected the communication.*

source:http://gutenberg.net.au/ebooks03/0301051h.html _ hos by acd

Comment: Downvoting and voting to close this question that quotes from The History of Spiritualism, an obscure piece of literature (or occult) even if it was written by A.C. Doyle, which is its only redeeming factor. The user abused the community by creating multiple accounts, in order to post a fantastical large number of questions, maybe as many as 100.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it, the medium was 'told' of his whereabouts during his railway journey. *While* has its normal meaning.

Comment: yes. but it seems that his visit to the west was after the traveling between Cleveland and Toledo. it is more intellectual because after that he says :"So thoughts have been uttered on subjects not then in my mind, and utterly at variance with my own notions". i conclude that the mudium knew his whereabouts and his conditions whereas he was unaware of them at that time.

Comment: I read it that the journey to Toledo was part of the 'visit to the West'.

Comment: it became ambiguous for me again. which Toledo? "Toledo
City in Ohio" or "Toledo, Spain" or another Toledo that i don't know?

Comment: Now you're being silly. How could anyone travel by train from Cleveland, Ohio to Spain?

Comment: ok. you are right. well done.